# Have object rotate another object in array?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, rotation

Hey everyone so I have an object `character` that initially rotates around the first Movie Clip called `planet` which isn't apart of the array. So the user can tap the screen and the `character` shoots in direction it is rotating. The objective is to have the `character` hit the other planets in a array and when it does have it start rotating around it just like the original. Everything works fine except when I shoot the character and it lands on one of the `outerplanets` in `aPlanetArray` it doesn't start rotating around that new planet but rather just disappears.

Here is how I set it up:

character Orbits first planet that is not in the array just have it as intial orbit then remove it once leaves to other outerPlanets:

```
private function startOrbit():void 
    {
        //add Planet 
        planet.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2);
        planet.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2) + 100;
        stage.addChild(planet);

        //radnom number set up in main class 
        if (randomOrbit == 1) //If equals to one then clock wise 
        {
            clockWiseOrbiter(); 
        }else
        if (randomOrbit == 2) //If equals to one then counter clock wise 
        {
            counterClockWiseOrbiter();
        }

    }
```

I add outer Planets in array:

```
private function addOuterPlanets():void 
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < nPlanets; i++)
        {
            outerPlanets = new mcOuterPlanets();
            outerPlanets.x = startPoint.x + (xSpacing * i);
            outerPlanets.y = startPoint.y - (ySpacing * i);
            stage.addChild(outerPlanets);
            aPlanetArray.push(outerPlanets);

        }
    }
```

In my Enter Frame Handler:

```
private function logicHandler(e:Event):void 
    {
        if (!tap && !nextlevel)
        {
            startOrbit(); //start player orbit around planet
        }

        if (nextlevel)
        {
            startNewOrbit();
            trace("Starting new Orbit");
        }

        //When tapped have outher planets move down


        if (tap)
        {
            characterTap(); //Character shoots from position
        }

        collisionPlanetHandler();
    }
```

When the collision happens with Outer Planets:

**** EDIT*****

```
private function collisionPlanetHandler():void 
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < aPlanetArray.length; i++)
        {
            var currentPlanet:mcOuterPlanets = aPlanetArray[i];

            if (character.hitTestObject(currentPlanet[i]) && !nextlevel)
            {
                trace("HIT");
                //Have charcter orbit that planet
                //startNewOrbit();

                //tap back to false
                tap = false;
                nextlevel = true;
                character.destroy();
                planet.destroy();
                planetHit = currentPlanet[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

When the character collides with the outerPlanets in array I have the New orbit happen around the OuterPlanet it lands on. Or I at least try:

```
private function startNewOrbit():void 
    {
        newClockWise();
    }

    private function newClockWise():void 
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < aPlanetArray.length; i++)
        {
            var currentPlanet:mcOuterPlanets = aPlanetArray[i];

            stage.addChild(character);
            character.rotation = (Math.atan2(character.y - currentPlanet.y, character.x - currentPlanet.x) * 180 / Math.PI);


            var rad:Number = angle * (Math.PI / 180); // Converting Degrees To Radians
            character.x = currentPlanet.x + radius * Math.cos(rad); // Position The Orbiter Along x-axis
            character.y = currentPlanet.y + radius * Math.sin(rad); // Position The Orbiter Along y-axis
            angle += speed; // Object will orbit clockwise
        }

    }
```

I know I am doing something wrong in the `startNewOrbit` and `newClockWise` functions. I have a for loop and I am trying to target the object in array it touches. I use this `var currentPlanet:mcOuterPlanets = aPlanetArray[i];` But not sure if I need to use `currentObject` or something equivalent. Does anyone have any idea what i am doing wrong why its not orbiting the new planet it touches but rather just disappears completely?

Comment: Does "starting new orbit" get traced?

Comment: Yes it does get traced.

Comment: Your new clockwise function is looping through all the planets and putting the character at the X/y of each planet in the array and doing this each frame. Right?  Why?

Comment: Yes you are correct it is doing that. I believe it is doing that because it is not targeting the specific Object in the array that it collided with. instead of stopping at that planet it is looping through them all. Hmm....

Comment: Okay @NealDavis I added a 'break;' at the end of the loop and it works now. Thank you for making me think more logical. Is this a crude way of accomplishing this though?

Comment: @NealDavis   Well I almost have it fixed. Whenever I try and land on a planet farther than the one closest to the character it collides fine but always spawns the character on the wrong planet. any ideas?

Comment: No it's fine. Good job with the break.

Comment: Yeah you need to have a variable outside the loop that holds a value of which planet is current planet. In your loop you're just declaring the first one to be the current one. Instead, when a collision occurs you set the variable to be that planet. Then you don't even have to loop rough the array, you can just use that variable. Or you can loop through the array until you find the right planet.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you for your help. I understand what your saying but struggling with how I would go about doing it. Ill try to work with that though.

Comment: I'll post a simple example

Comment: Awesome that would definitely give me some perspective. Thank you

Comment: Obviously you can't just copy and paste this code. It's pseudo code, but since you know how to loop through arrays and do hit tests and all that... this example just shows the idea. Let me know if it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var planetHit:MovieClip;

function collisionTest():void{
    for (loop through planets){
        if (planet[i].hitTestObject(character)){
            planetHit = planet[i];
        }
    }
}
```

See now the planet at that location in the array *is* (==) `planetHit` so then you can do

```
character.x = planetHit.x;
```

or

```
planetHit.addChild(character);
```

etc.

Comment: Edited to include the variable declaration outside of any functions

Comment: I Understand what your doing here only problem is when I do this "if (character.hitTestObject(currentPlanet[i]) && !nextlevel)" I get this error: Property 0 not found on mcOuterPlanets and there is no default value.

Comment: Post the whole function as an edit (click edit below your post)

Comment: Yeah you don't need the [i] because you've already said that `currentPlanet` is `aPlanetArray[i]`

Comment: Okay awesome it works perfect now. I removed the whole Loop statement as you said I could as well as the [i] and everything is running smoothly thank you Neal for taking the time out of the day.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped.